# tree-sitter match for similar structures

Tags: grammar, treesitter

I'm trying to create a [tree-sitter](https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/creating-parsers) for a Minecraft function grammar.

The structure of the language looks like this:

```
command @e[key=value] other args
```

I'm having an issue with the value in the second argument (the target selector) in the above example. This value can be many things, like strings, numbers, booleans, and two similar object structures (NBT and scoreboard object).

Here are examples of each:

NBT

```js
{key:value}
```

Scoreboard Object

```
{key=number} // where number is: N, ..N, N.., or N..N
```

My grammar file contains the following code:

```js
// unrelated code removed

module.exports = grammar({
  name: "mcfunction",
  rules: {
    root: $ => repeat(
      choice(
        $.command
      )
    ),
    command: $ => prec.right(seq(
      field("command_name", $.identifier),
      repeat(
        choice(
          $.selector
        )
      ),
      "\n"
    )),
    identifier: $ => /[A-Za-z][\w-]+/,
    number: $ => prec(1, /-?\d+(\.\d+)?/),
    boolean: $ => choice(
      "true",
      "false"
    ),
    string: $ => seq(
      "\"",
      repeat(
        choice(
          $._escape_sequence,
          /[^"]/
        )
      ),
      "\""
    ),
    _escape_sequence: $ => seq("\\", "\""),
    selector: $ => seq(
      token(
        seq(
          "@",
          choice(
            "p", "a", "e", "s", "r"
          )
        )
      ),
      optional(
        seq(
          token.immediate("["),
          optional(
            repeat(
              seq(
                $.selector_option,
                optional(",")
              )
            )
          ),
          "]"
        )
      ),
    ),
    selector_option: $ => seq(
      $.selector_key,
      "=",
      $.selector_value
    ),
    selector_key: $ => /[a-z_-]+/,
    selector_value: $ => choice(
      $.item,
      $.path,
      $.selector_key,
      $.selector_number,
      $.number,
      $.boolean,
      $.selector_object
    ),
    selector_number: $ => prec.right(1, choice(
      seq(
        "..",
        $.number
      ),
      seq(
        $.number,
        "..",
        $.number
      ),
      seq(
        $.number,
        ".."
      ),
      $.number
    )),
    selector_object: $ => choice(
      seq(
        "{",
        repeat(
          seq(
            $.selector_score,
            optional(",")
          )
        ),
        "}"
      ),
      seq(
        "{",
        repeat(
          seq(
            $.selector_nbt,
            optional(",")
          )
        ),
        "}"
      )
    ),
    selector_nbt: $ => seq(
      $.nbt_object_key,
      ":",
      $.nbt_object_value
    ),
    selector_score: $ => seq(
      field("selector_score_key", $.selector_key),
      "=",
      field("selector_score_value", $.selector_number)
    ),
    _namespace: $ => /[a-z_-]+:/,
    item: $ => seq(
      $._namespace,
      $.selector_key
    ),
    path: $ => seq(
      choice($.item, /[a-z_]+/),
      repeat1(
        token("/", /[a-z_]/)
      )
    ),
    nbt: $ => choice(
      $.nbt_array,
      $.nbt_object
    ),
    nbt_object: $ => seq(
      "{",
      repeat(
        seq(
          $.nbt_object_key,
          ":",
          $.nbt_object_value,
          optional(",")
        )
      ),
      "}"
    ),
    nbt_array: $ => seq(
      "[",
      repeat(
        seq(
          $.nbt_object_value,
          optional(",")
        )
      ),
      "]"
    ),
    nbt_object_key: $ => choice(
      $.string,
      $.number,
      $.identifier
    ),
    nbt_object_value: $ => choice(
      $.string,
      $.nbt_number,
      $.boolean,
      $.nbt
    ),
    nbt_number: $ => seq(
      $.number,
      field("nbt_number_suffix", optional(choice("l","s","d","f","b")))
    )
  }
});
```

However, if I compile and parse `test @e[scores={example=1..}]`, I get:

```
(root [0, 0] - [6, 0]
  (command [0, 0] - [1, 0]
    command_name: (identifier [0, 0] - [0, 4])
    (selector [0, 5] - [0, 29]
      (selector_option [0, 8] - [0, 28]
        (selector_key [0, 8] - [0, 14])
        (selector_value [0, 15] - [0, 28]
          (selector_object [0, 15] - [0, 28]
            (ERROR [0, 16] - [0, 27]
              (nbt_object_key [0, 16] - [0, 23]
                (identifier [0, 16] - [0, 23]))))))))
tests/test.mcfunction  0 ms    (ERROR [0, 16] - [0, 27])
```

Expected: instead of `ERROR`, it should be `selector_score`, and there should be a `score_key` and `score_value`.

This does not happen if I remove the `selector_nbt` sequence from `selector_object`. However, if running the parse (with both sequences or just the `selector_nbt`) on a command using nbt data, there are no errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a `choice` of the two conflicting keys, something like this:

```js
choice(
  alias($.key_1, $.key_2),
  $.key_2
)
```

ahlinc on [GitHub](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter/discussions/1310) answered:

> You can fix your error for the above grammar by assigning lexer precedence for the `selector_key` terminal over the `identifier` terminal like:
>
> ```js
> selector_key: $ => token(prec(1, /[a-z_-]+/)),
> ```
>
> But you need to note that you use regexps that clashes:
>
> ```js
> identifier: $ => /[A-Za-z][\w-]+/,
> selector_key: $ => token(prec(1, /[a-z_-]+/)),
> ```
>
> If it's impossible to rewrite the above regexps to don't have conflicts in them then you may need a workaround described here: [#1287 (reply in thread)](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter/discussions/1287#discussioncomment-1040284)